# Redmine modification for issue number

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I would like to hide the issue number on the issue list.
I use "Redmine 2.3.1" and the file to achieve that is this file: `./app/views/issues/_list.html.erb`

It contains this line:

```
<%= raw query.inline_columns.map {|column| "<td class=\"#{column.css_classes}\">#{column_content(column, issue)}</td>"}.join%>
```

And the array `query.inline_columns` contains the id for example. I thought modifying this array would help me with my problem, but the changes aren't saved.

This is what I tried:

```
<%= @query.inline_columns.inspect %>
=> [#<QueryColumn:0x00000003607928 @name=:id ... and so on>]
<% @query.inline_columns.delete_at(0) %> 
=>
<%= @query.inline_columns.inspect %>
=> [#<QueryColumn:0x00000003607928 @name=:id ... and so on>]
```

Why was the `delete_at` useless? And how would I modify this array or hide the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note:

`@query.inline_columns` might not an array. It may quack like an `Array`, but it's not.

`@query.inline_columns.delete_at(0)` should have returned something. Did it return and you ommited?

And last, but not least, the most probable guess I can make:

`@query.inline_columns` fetches something, converts it to an array and dups it before returning. The only way you can do something like that would be:

```
some_columns = @query.inline_columns
some_columns.delete_at(0)
some_columns
```

Comment: This is helpful, as I now know that it wasn't an array. How would I achieve to manipulate the query.inline_columns?

Comment: I'd need to know what @query is, first.

Comment: It is this object:
https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/query.rb#L119

There you also can find "inline_columns".

Comment: They are records from the database. I would not remove them directly before figuring out what they do. This approach is definitely better.

Comment: I added a solution. Just check my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution now:

```
<% if @project.id == 1 %>
  <% @qcols =  query.inline_columns.reject{ |col| col.name.to_s == 'id' } %>
<% else %>
  <% @qcols =  query.inline_columns.each %>
<% end %>
```

So I took advantage of the reject method. And then I work with the @qcols.

*Posted on behalf of OP.*